# c++ - delete dynamic memory allocation from function but unable to reach the variable

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a dynamic memory allocation of `List`. How can I erase this memory when the program ends?

Outside the function I do not have access to `newList` and if I erase it in function and delete the `newList` before I return, then basically I return nothing.

Is `newList` deleted automatically when the program terminates or do I need to manually delete it?

## main.cpp:

```
//reverse the list, return new list 
List* reverseList(List &listToReverse) {

    //dynamic memory allocation
    List* newList = new List;

    //pointer to first node
    Node* currentPtr = listToReverse.getFirstNode(); 

    while (currentPtr != 0) {
        newList->AddElement(currentPtr->getdata());
        currentPtr = currentPtr->getNextPtr();
    }

    Node* currentNode = newList->getFirstNode();

    int size = newList->size();

    while (currentNode != 0) {
        currentNode->setId(size);
        size--;
        currentNode = currentNode->getNextPtr();
    }

    return newList;
}

int main() {

    List l1;

    cout << "The reversed list: " << endl;
    reverseList(l1)->print();    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145799/how-to-delete-a-pointer-after-returning-its-value-inside-a-function

Comment: Look up smart pointers

Answer (score 1):

To fix you issue, you have a couple of solution:

- store the pointer in a variable (in the main) and delete it (not the best solution)
- return an automatic variable (not a pointer), the destructor will be called when the variable go out of scope (beware of shallow copy issues*) (check out move semantic)
- use smart pointer

With modern OS, the memory will be cleaned after your program terminates **BUT** this is not a solution ! **Always clean up every resources you have used !**

* If you make a shallow copy and your type have (raw) pointers, the pointer inside the copy will point to the same object as the original. Which means that once the original delete his memory, the pointers in the copy will point to invalid memory.